# Same mnemonic gives different keys in trust wallet and in polkadot.js

Tags: key, wallet

I want to transfer the management of my dot account from polkadat.js to trustwallet. The problem I am facing is that the same mnemonic give different key in those applications. How to deal with that? How to add the dot account to my trust wallet? I have both mnemonic phrase and the recovery json file stored.

Test mnemonic: neck glance normal build soccer reason cotton island story control lemon theme

public key on polkadot.js: 162LT7DYzo3iHGfk3RDpZWeYq5NUxxmvZCFUMTAwuFYZYp89

public key in trust wallet: 16GEpjTJJgSX9Saoe7Y7uTDX78h6bAB6uiHhnXJ9AFXmUxby

Comment: Could be that they use a different crypto as default. You can use `subkey inspect` to check the derived key for all three different supported signature algorithms. One of them should match.

Answer (score 0):

Different key derivation functions affect the ability to use the same mnemonic in multiple wallets as different wallets may use different functions to derive the secret from the mnemonic. See more information in the docs: [Portability](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-account-advanced#portability).

PolkadotJS uses BIP32, but I can't find what key derivation Trust wallet uses but probably a different one. In that case the only thing you can try is export/import the private key directly.